# How to Read Value with Backslashes in json or javascript or jquery

Tags: php, javascript, json, jquery

I need to transfer value/s (Windows path) to json using jQuery Ajax so that the value will be thrown or decoded to PHP script, but it can't read value/s with backslashes in json.  It must be transferred to json value with the whole path with backslashes in it.

My Sample Codes:

```
/*==========================================================================*/


var file_name = "C:\WINDOWS\Temp\phpABD.tmp";

var jsonSearchContent = "{\"file_name\":\""+file_name+"\"}";


            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                dataType: "html",
                url: url,
                data: {sendValue:jsonSearchContent},
                complete: function (upload) {
                    alert(upload.responseText);
                }
            }
            );
/*==========================================================================*/
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error/problem you're running into?

Answer (score 5):

Escape it.

```
var file_name = "C:\\WINDOWS\\Temp\\phpABD.tmp";
```

By the way, you don't need to use json format to send to php, just send the value directly and not necessary to do `json_decode` in php side.

```
data: {file_name: file_name},
```

Answer (score 3):

The backslash character in javascript is used to escape special characters like tabs, carriage returns, etc.  In a javascript string, if you want to represent an actual backslash character,  use `'\\'` and it will be treated as a single backslash.  Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: url,
    data: {
        sendValue: {
            file_name: "C:\\WINDOWS\\Temp\\phpABD.tmp"
        }
    },
    complete: function (upload) {
        alert(upload.responseText);
    }
});
```

[Here's the w3schools page on javascript strings](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_string.asp).

Comment: thanks sir @Dan.  By the way, I also need to replace "C:\WINDOWS\Temp\phpABD.tmp"; to "C:\\WINDOWS\\Temp\\phpABD.tmp";

but the when I tried to use 

file_name.replace("\\","\\\\");

still doesn't work. Many more thanks in advance sir.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that.  You only need to escape it if it's a literal string like `"C:\\file\\path.txt"`.  If you already have reference to a string, you don't need to replace \ with \\.  If you will be more descriptive than "doesn't work", I will try to help you.